# list has no attribute 'send_keys' in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

i tried to automate instagram login.here is my code

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from cofig import *

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

sleep(2)

username_input = browser.find_elements_by_name('username')
username_input.send_keys(USERNAME)
password_input = browser.find_elements_by_name('password')
password_input.send_keys(PASSWORD)


login_button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('button[type="submit"]')
login_button.click()


browser.close()
```

cofig is another file which holds my instagram username and password.but i got an error saying list has no attribute 'send_keys'.here is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bot.py", line 13, in <module>
username_input.send_keys(USERNAME)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, `browser.find_elements_by_name()` returns a list of elements, not an element. `send_key()` is a method on the elements of that list, but it is not a method of the list itself.

The following code is calling `send_keys()` on the first element of that list instead, and should fix your problem as long as the list has at least one element:

```
username_input = browser.find_elements_by_name('username')
username_input[0].send_keys(USERNAME)
password_input = browser.find_elements_by_name('password')
password_input[0].send_keys(PASSWORD)
```